# DynamoDB query group of category

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have this table:

```
PRODUCT_TABLE:
Partition: appId (String)
Sort: productId (String)
category
```

I want to retrieve all the distinct categories (like using `GROUP BY` in SQL)
Is there a way to achieve that?
Or, should I add another table just for entering all the categories?

Comment: you should better use sql database for sql like use cases(if too many frequently changing categories)

Comment: @bestwishes nope, there are no frequently changing categories

Comment: are the categories hierarchal like country#state#city or independent ones?

Comment: independent, the categories are just like "Shoes" , "Watches", "Shirts", etc @bestwishes

Comment: if you search enough you can make many to many relationship in dynamodb. but i would suggest you to go to sql database. Even if you have large amount of data you can scale it considerably by doing sharding. If you are not dealing with large large amount of data its no brainer to go to a sql store